Главный модуль Битрикс
Мне необходимо использовать входящий вебхук,  в файле куда отправляются данные подключен модуль битрикс. Из-за этого скрипт не выполняется, что можно сделать ?
<?
define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NO_AGENT_CHECK", true);
define('PUBLIC_AJAX_MODE', true);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
$_SESSION["SESS_SHOW_INCLUDE_TIME_EXEC"] = "N";
$APPLICATION->ShowIncludeStat = false;

file_put_contents('logs.txt', print_r("\n" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n", true), FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('logs.txt', print_r(1, true), FILE_APPEND);

require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php");


Очень мало данных. Что значит не выполняется? Есть ли ошибки? На странице? В логах?
